# pandas - AttributeError 'dataframe' object has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, attributeerror

I am trying to filter out the dataframe that contains a list of product. However,  I am getting the `pandas - 'dataframe' object has no attribute 'str'` error whenever I run the code.

Here is the line of code:

```py
include_clique = log_df.loc[log_df['Product'].str.contains("Product A")]
```

Product is an object datatype.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("FILE.csv", header = None)

headerName = ["DRID", "Product", "M24", "M23", "M22", "M21"] 
data.columns = [headerName]

log_df = np.log(1 + data[["M24", "M23", "M22", "M21"]])
copy = data[["DRID", "Product"]].copy()
log_df = copy.join(log_df)

include_clique = log_df.loc[log_df['Product'].str.contains("Product A")]
```

Here is the head:

```
       ID  PRODUCT       M24       M23       M22  M21
0  123421        A  0.000000  0.000000  1.098612  0.0   
1  141840        A  0.693147  1.098612  0.000000  0.0   
2  212006        A  0.693147  0.000000  0.000000  0.0   
3  216097        A  1.098612  0.000000  0.000000  0.0   
4  219517        A  1.098612  0.693147  1.098612  0.0
```

Comment: Your code should work. Are you sure you are not doing `log_df.str` somewhere (instead of `log_df['Product'].str`)? Or maybe you have *duplicated indexes* with this name `Product` (e.g. two columns with same name) ?

Comment: @RafaelC yes I am positive. It was working yesterday, but now it is not working anymore.

Comment: What do you see for `type(log_df['Product'])` ?

Comment: @RafaelC no, there are no duplicated indexes.

Comment: @jpp pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: @DavidLuong, So now what do you see for `type(log_df)` ?

Comment: @jpp pandas.core.frame.DataFrame for type(log_df)

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have extra brackets, e.g. `log_df[['Product']]`? Otherwise, I think you need to share a reproducible example.

Comment: @jpp yes i am sure,  I will share the entire code with you.

Comment: @RafaelC I can't share that because it is confidential information.. But I get 3.6 million products that have been sold.

Comment: Post only the first five lines of your `df` and change whatever confidential info to `foo`, `bar`, `blablabla` etc. Just want to understand the structure of your `df`

Comment: @RafaelC sorry, kind of new to stackoverflow. I will post it in the body.

Comment: @RafaelC Done, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: @roganjosh 0.23.3

Comment: Add the column names too

Comment: @RafaelC Got it

Comment: problem lies in the line of code np.log,
log_df = np.log(1+data[["M24","M23","M22","M21","M20","M19","M18","M17","M16","M15","M14","M13","M12","M11","M10","M9","M8","M7","M6","M5","M4","M3","M2","M1"]])

Comment: @Mr.J do you have any suggestions?

Comment: yes, i found problem but i need your input. can you please print  print(data) after line data.columns=[headerName]. give me output result. the problem seems to be column mapping with Product.

Comment: just show me 3X4 rows

Comment: @Mr.J i printed it out. it seems whenever i print it out, the product is not actually under the column.

Comment: exactly that is what causing the issue on conversion to str, since right columns names are not getting mapped.

Comment: @Mr.J can you please help me on how to fix this problem? I am inexperienced with python. Also, it was working fine yesterday. Do you have any idea why it might not work anymore?

Comment: add columns names as parameter to dataframe on creation. or put columns as header to csv file. something like this.

data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123421,141840,212006],'PRODUCT':['A','A','A'],'M24':[0.000000,0.693147,0.693147],'M23':[0.000000,1.098612,0.693147]},columns=["ID","Product","M24","M23"])

Comment: @Mr.J i  added it as a parameter and it still is not working.

Comment: @Mr.J i am doing data =pd.read_csv("file.csv" names= "A...")

Comment: @Mr.J whenever I print out 'data' alone, it looks like it is getting mapped, but print(data) still doesnt map it.

Comment: this works for me, try to change your accordingly. 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cl = ['ID','PRODUCT','M24','M23']
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123421,141840,212006],
                     'PRODUCT':["A","A","A"],
                      'M24':[0.000000,0.693147,0.693147],'M23':[0.000000,1.098612,0.693147]},columns=cl)
data.set_index('ID')
log_df = np.log(1+data[['M24','M23']])
log_df = data[["ID","PRODUCT"]].copy().join(log_df)
include_clique = log_df.loc[log_df['PRODUCT'].str.contains("A")]
include_clique

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: @Mr.J i might be wrong, but I am still able to call data["product"] .. if this was not mapped, wouldn't an error occur?

Comment: are you getting correct product data?

Comment: @Mr.J yeah i am, i did data.product.unique() i noticed that there is a bunch of white space, which makes the print(data) look awkward.

Comment: try to strip white spaces on columns

Comment: okay, i'm not sure what happened but everything works now. i didn't change any code at all. i ignored the white space without striping it and it works for me... well thank you for your help. this is confusing me..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Short answer:** change `data.columns=[headerName]` into `data.columns=headerName`

**Explanation:** when you set `data.columns=[headerName]`, the columns are MultiIndex object. Therefore, your `log_df['Product']` is a DataFrame and for DataFrame, there is no `str` attribute.

When you set `data.columns=headerName`, your `log_df['Product']` is a single column and you can use `str` attribute.

For any reason, if you need to keep your data as MultiIndex object, there is another solution: first convert your `log_df['Product']` into Series. After that, `str` attribute is available.

```
products = pd.Series(df.Product.values.flatten())
include_clique = products[products.str.contains("Product A")]
```

However, I guess the first solution is what you're looking for

Comment: If entries in the column are NaN, you may still run into problems and require this answer's 2nd solution. I had an unexpected scenario where some of my `df['column']` were single columns and others were DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

You get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute ...` when you try to access an attribute your dataframe doesn't have.

A common case is when you try to select a column using `.` instead of `[]` when the column name contains white space (e.g. `'col1 '`).

```py
df.col1       # <--- error
df['col1 ']   # <--- no error
```

Another common case is when you try to call a Series method on a DataFrame. For example, `tolist()` (or `map()`) are Series methods so they must be called on a column. If you call them on a DataFrame, you'll get

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

As [hoang tran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52552220/19123103) explains, this is what is happening with OP as well. `.str` is a Series accessor and it's not implemented for DataFrames.

Yet another case is if you have a typo and try to call/access an attribute that's simply not defined; e.g. if you try to call `rows()` instead of `iterrows()`, you'll get

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rows'
```

You can check the full list of attributes using the following comprehension.

```py
[x for x in dir(pd.DataFrame) if not x.startswith('_')]
```

---

When you assign column names as `df.columns = [['col1', 'col2']]`, `df` is a MultiIndex dataframe now, so to access each column, you'll need to pass a tuple:

```py
df['col1'].str.contains('Product A')    # <---- error
df['col1',].str.contains('Product A')   # <---- no error; note the trailing comma
```

In fact, you can pass a tuple to select a column of any MultiIndex dataframe, e.g.

```py
df['level_1_colname', 'level_2_colname'].str.contains('Product A')
```

---

You can also flatten a MultiIndex column names by mapping a "flattener" function on it. A common one is `''.join`:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```