# 'dataframe' object has no attribute 'str' problem

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete rows that contain certain strings. However, I am getting the error:

> pandas - 'dataframe' object has no attribute 'str' error.

Here is my code:

```
df = df[~df['colB'].str.contains('Example:')]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Show us your Dataframe sample.

Comment: colA         colB                                  colC
Alex   Example: some string 15.00
Jim         Example:  other string 12.15
John  clear                          5.00
Marc         Yellow                         2.00

Comment: So your error means that df['colB'] does not return a Series, it returns a DataFrame, and for a DataFrame there is no str attribute. Without investigating the actual df we can't really help you.

Comment: This might help you out.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502263/pandas-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-str

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas - 'dataframe' object has no attribute 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502263/pandas-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-str)

Comment: show the dataframe sample in the question not in comments

Answer (score 9):

First problem shoud be duplicated columns names, so after select `colB` get not `Series`, but `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Example: s', 'as', 2], ['dd', 'aaa', 3]], columns=['colB','colB','colC'])
print (df)
         colB colB  colC
0  Example: s   as     2
1          dd  aaa     3

print (df['colB'])
         colB colB
0  Example: s   as
1          dd  aaa

#print (df['colB'].str.contains('Example:'))
#>AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Solution should be join columns together:

```
print (df['colB'].apply(' '.join, axis=1))
0    Example: s as
1           dd aaa

df['colB'] = df.pop('colB').apply(' '.join, axis=1)
df = df[~df['colB'].str.contains('Example:')] 
print (df)
   colC    colB
1     3  dd aaa
```

---

Second problem  should be  `hidden` MultiIndex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Example: s', 'as', 2], ['dd', 'aaa', 3]], columns=['colA','colB','colC'])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns])
print (df)
         colA colB colC
0  Example: s   as    2
1          dd  aaa    3

print (df['colB'])
  colB
0   as
1  aaa

#print (df['colB'].str.contains('Example:'))
#>AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Solution is reassign first level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
df = df[~df['colB'].str.contains('Example:')] 
print (df)
         colA colB  colC
0  Example: s   as     2
1          dd  aaa     3
```

And third should be `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Example: s', 'as', 2], ['dd', 'aaa', 3]], columns=['colA','colB','colC'])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['a']])
print (df)
         colA colB colC
            a    a    a
0  Example: s   as    2
1          dd  aaa    3

print (df['colB'])
     a
0   as
1  aaa

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['colA', 'colB', 'colC'], ['a']],
           codes=[[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0]])

#print (df['colB'].str.contains('Example:'))
#>AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Solution is select `MultiIndex` by `tuple`:

```
df1 = df[~df[('colB', 'a')].str.contains('Example:')] 
print (df1)
         colA colB colC
            a    a    a
0  Example: s   as    2
1          dd  aaa    3
```

Or reassign back:

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
df2 = df[~df['colB'].str.contains('Example:')] 
print (df2)
         colA colB  colC
0  Example: s   as     2
1          dd  aaa     3
```

Or remove second level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
df2 = df[~df['colB'].str.contains('Example:')] 
print (df2)
         colA colB  colC
0  Example: s   as     2
1          dd  aaa     3
```

Comment: Came here because I had duplicate columns, as the first part of this says. So obvious once I saw it; how did I not figure that out immediately? The pointer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`df[[~df.iloc[i,:].str.contains('String_to_match').any()  for i in range(0,len(df))]]`