# How to map two dataframes keeping the value same for one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, etl

Im trying to write a script for few ETL transformations. I have 34 fixed columns i.e. df1,  according to which I have to map the column name of different input files containing different columns i.e. df2.

df1(Standard Columns):

[image: df1 : Standard Columns]

df2:

[image: df2: input file]

I have tried `df.merge` but that does not seem to solve my problem.

The expected result is the columns in the input file `df2` to be mapped with `same column name` as `df1` and `same order` as they appaer in `df2`with its original value intact.

Expected Result :

[image: Result]

any help will be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: df1. is dataframe ?

Comment: A sample output would probably help make it clear what you're trying to do

Comment: This is not clear.  Many people avoid answering questions that aren't clear because it is a potential waste of time.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Wen-Ben yes df1 is a dataframe with standard columns.

Comment: @G.Anderson attached an image.

Comment: @piRSquared sorry for not being clear, edited my question.

Comment: For future reference, please don't post data as pictures. We can't run tests on pictures. `df.head()` and `df1.head()` posted as code-formatted text would be much more useful

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this would be to have an intermediate step of mapping the columns.
For instance:

```
df2.rename(columns = {'Department Code':'Field 1 Dept Number','Column2':'2_column', .....})
```

And then you can merge the two dataframes on the columns of interest.

Comment: Thanks, this could be helpful, but there are 34  standard columns for df1, and columns in df2 might vary in name as well as number and order they appear. Is there any dynamic way of doing this.

Comment: I understand what you are saying..perhaps one faster way would be to match regular expression in the columns..But ultimately you are going to need to verify the mapping is happening correctly to get your desired output(which is merging the df's rightly)

Comment: @K.S Assuming your `df1` has all labels in column 'A', then you could create the mapping dict like `head_map={k : df1['A'].values[i] for i,k in enumerate(df2.columns.values)}` and use this as `df2.rename(columns=head_map)`, but only if your `df1` contains all required labels, and if they are in the correct order already.

Comment: @K.S Please upvote if my answer has been worthwhile

Comment: @Asmus I got a `KeyError: 'A'`, i tried doing `head_map={k : df1[1:].values[i] for i,k in enumerate(df2.columns.values)}`, this seems to work, but `df.rename` is not working. The output file is same as the input.

Comment: @asimo Will your approach keep the original value same ?

Comment: @K.S well you will have to use the actual name of the respective column in df1; if you're unsure, try `print(df.head(5))` and pick the actual column label which contains all your `FIELD …` labels. Did you remember to actually *store* the renamed `df2`, i.e. `df2=df2.rename(columns=head_map)`?

Comment: @Asmus The column `A` contains the actual name. That's the only column in that dataframe and csv file. Also I tried `df2=df2.rename(columns=head_map)` and it changes the `column name` but value is not correct for that data. The result im getting is `['FIELD 3\xa0 SubClass number\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 '] ['FIELD 4\xa0 SubSubClass number\xa0 '] ['FIELD 5\xa0 SKU\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 '] ['FIELD 6\xa0 Desc\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 ']` something like this with value for earlier column.

Comment: Try removing `\xa0` (the non-breaking whitespace) via `df1['A']=df1['A'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\\xa0', '')` *before declaring* the `head_map`.

Comment: @Asmus getting error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: @K.S You could have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55643467/565489), for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192955/discussion-between-k-s-and-asmus).