# I would like to extract certain part of a string from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I have vast number of columns containing this kind of data:

```
DE-JP-202/2066/A2@qwier.cu/68
NL-LK-02206/2136/A1@ozmmfts.de/731
OM-PH-31303222/3671/Z1@jtqy.ml/524
```

I would like to extract string between '@' and '.' and between '.' and '/'
into two separete colums .

Like :

```
txt 1      txt 2
qwier       cu
ozmmft      de
jtqy        ml
```

Tried:

```
x = dane.str.extract(r'@(?P<txt1>\d)\.(?P<txt2>[ab\d])/')
```

But doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get 2 capturing groups, you could use 2 [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

In the first group match 1+ times any char except a dot `[^.]+`

In the second group match 1+ times any char except a forward slash `[^/]+`

```
@(?P<txt1>[^.]+)\.(?P<txt2>[^/]+)/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oVHO7S/1)

Comment: Was just about to add a regex demo for you, nice one, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: What if error: DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
occur?  I have dataset with 60 colums like in exmple above and my code looks like ```dane = p.read_csv('dane.csv',delimiter=';')


x = dane.str.extract(r'@(?P<txt1>[^.]+)\.(?P<txt2>[^/]+)')

Comment: @Matadora Perhaps this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502263/pandas-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-str can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the formatting of your strings all have only 1 `@` and 1 `.`. You can do the following:

`s = 'DE-JP-202/2066/A2@qwier.cu/68'`

`column1 = s.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]`

`column2 = s.split('@')[1].split('.')[1].split('/')[0]`

Comment: What if I have huge amount of columns and this error occures while using your solution :'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: And I have like data set with 60 colums and 20576 rows

Comment: Can you cast DataFrame object to a string? For example, str(s).split('@')[1].split('.')[0]