# Filtering out rows with strings in a dataframe, which do not contain certain words, using Python

Tags: python, string, text, nlp

I have a dataframe with a column 'text".

I want to filter out everything else but rows in a `text` column, containing certain strings.
And my list of words is long. For example, crime, taxation, etc.

This works for one word:

```
data_cleaned = data_cleaned.loc[data_cleaned['text'].str.contains('population')].reset_index(drop = True)
```

How to add multiple words, having not only population, but crime etc.

I see answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502263/pandas-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-str), but it does not work for me.

UPD.

My full list of words looks like this

```
key_words = ['population'
                          'migrarion'
                          'crime',
                          'safety',
                          'taxation',
                          'taxes',
                          'weather', 
                          'climate',
                          'opportunities',
                          'employment',
                          'unemployment',
                          'cultural life',
                          'services',
                          'jobs',
                          'economic growth',
                          'economic decline',
                          'pollution',
                          'environment',
                          'health',
                          'insurance',
                          'education',
                          'natural disaster',
                          'retirement']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `lst` is the list of strings the following would work:

```
def selector(s):
    for w in lst:
        if w in s:
            return True
    return False

data_cleaned = data_cleaned.loc[data_cleaned['text'].apply(selector)]
```